# Module over $F(G)$ written as a direct sum of copies of $F$

Tags: modules, representation-theory

I'm reading a proof that if $G$ is a finite group and $F$ is a field that's "good for $G$" (i.e., characteristic $0$ or coprime to $\mid G\mid$ and $X^{\mid G\mid} - 1$ splits in $F$ with no repeated roots), then every irreducible $F$-representation is one-dimensional iff and $G$ is abelian.

I'm stuck on the last step. the author claims that if $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis such that $\sigma(g)$ is diagonalizable with respect to $\mathcal B$ for all $g$, then
$$M\cong Fv_1\oplus\cdots\oplus Fv_n,$$
where $M$ is an irreducible representation of $G$.

I don't see why this last step is true.

Comment: @LukasHeger sorry yes. somehow forgot to include this. will update it. I forgot to say iff $G$ is abelian

Comment: @AnneBauval $M$ is an irreducible representation of $G$. Equivalently, $M$ is an irreducible left $F(G)$-module. will update the post

Comment: You say that “$σ(g)$ is diagonalizable with respect to $\mathcal{B}$”. But diagonalizability is a property of the endomorphism $σ(g)$, and doesn’t depend on a basis. Do you mean that $σ(g)$ is diagonalizable (making no mention of $\mathcal{B}$), that $σ(g)$ is diagonal with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ (which is stronger than just “diagonalizable”), or something else entirely?